# Example of stationary 2D Gaussian process with non-symmetric auto-covariance function

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t, Y_t)$ be a [stationary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) 2D [Gaussian process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process), therefore $\mathbb{E}\left(X_t\right) = \mathbb{E}(Y_t) = 0$.

I am looking for an *explicit* example of a valid [auto-covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance) matrix, i.e:
$$
 R(h) = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{E}\left(X_t X_{t+h}\right) & \mathbb{E}\left(X_t Y_{t+h}\right) \\
  \mathbb{E}\left(Y_t X_{t+h}\right) & \mathbb{E}\left(Y_t Y_{t+h}\right) \end{pmatrix}
$$
such that $R(h)$ is not symmetric for $h\not=0$. Thank you.

Comment: I fail to see why this was down-voted... If I am being signaled about a flaw in the question, please speak up. I'll try to improve it.

Comment: Somebody downvoted this question? Wow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your favorite stationary Gaussian process $(X_t)_t$ and define $(Y_t)_t$ by $Y_t=X_{t+\ell}$, for some nonzero $\ell$. Then $\mathbb E(X_tY_{t+h})=\mathbb E(X_0X_{\ell+h})$ is the covariance at distance $|\ell+h|$, while $\mathbb E(Y_tX_{t+h})=\mathbb E(X_0X_{h-\ell})$ is the covariance at distance $|\ell-h|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very useful for me.

Comment: This construction leads to a Gaussian process with degenerate covariance of some distinct-positive-time slices of the process, that is covariance of $(X_{t_1}, Y_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_n}, Y_{t_n} )$. I guess I need to revise the question.

Comment: I actually found that a vector valued ARMA process fits the bill.